# What's the difference between allowNull and required when defining a model with mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Is there any difference between `using required: true` and `allowNull: false` when defining an schema with mongoose?

```
const Schema = new Schema({
  questionId: {
    type: String,
    allowNull: false,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

Comment: There is no attribute like `allowNull` in mongoose validators... `required` does the same thing in mongoose as of  `allowNull` with SQL/sequelize...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose/Mongodb doesn't have `allowNull` option, although it doesn't throw any error if it sets.

If you want make a field required, only `required: true` does work